# Team City and Wix error

Tags: wix, teamcity, devops

I've been learning team city the last couple of weeks and have had some good success (fun!). In the last couple of days, I've also been looking to wix to create an installer. So basically I'm pretty new to both as an FYI.

All my projects build fine, however, my Wix project as its configured below fails to copy a file with and gives the error message below.

[Exec] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5088, 5): error MSB3073: The command "Rem Copy Server.dll and Server.pdb to executable directories
COPY "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\6dc243663a8a7b3c\Sirius\Server\bin\Release\Server.*"  "*Undefined*Sirius\bin\Release\" /Y" exited with code 1.

I suspect the issue is to do with the Undefined value in the path copy to the path but I'm not sure what I can do to resolve this issue.

Does anyone have any solution or advice TeamCity and Wix, I'd love to see some example configurations.

Thanks, guys and girls.

[image]

Comment: Check the post build event in the wix project, you may get an idea as to what the "Undefined" variable is.

Comment: Thanks, Santhosh, I've taken a look and I don't have any post-build events not even a default one. The error appears to be when building the referenced projects associated with the Wix project. However the when building same projects on their own in Team city I don't have any issues.